# Dojox FloatingPane is growing every time I update the content

Tags: layout, resize, dojo

I've created a simple mapping widget using Dojo and Google Maps. The map is displayed in a dijit.layout.ContentPane set as the center panel of a dijit.layout.BorderContainer (which has the address field and a BusyButton in its top panel); the BorderContainer is in turn wrapped in a dojox.layout.FloatingPane. The widget has a subscription to a topic that will trigger a refresh of the map display when new address data is provided. The updater function is very simple, and looks like this:

```
_updateAddress: function(data) {
    this.addressMapper.show();

    if (data === null || !data.address || data.address === "" ) {
        this.address.attr("value", "");
    } else {
        this.address.attr("value", data.address);
    }

    this.mapBtn.makeBusy();
    this._getMap();
}
```

Every time I call this function, the FloatingPane's resize() method is invoked when I call show(), and it's increasing the height and width of the BorderContainer by 12 pixels every time the pane is shown (even with doLayout and isLayoutContainer set to false on the FloatingPane). I can't seem to prevent this from happening, or correct it afterwards, no matter what I try.

Anyone have any ideas how to remedy this?

Thanks in advance!

-- Joe M --

Comment: ::sigh:: Never mind. Did some more Google searching, and apparently there's a 4-year old open bug on exactly this issue. Looks like I just have to deal with it.

See http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5849